# The requested URL /read was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I'm new in php. So one man recommended me to execute step by step this tutorial - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html (before chapter "Add a Touch of Symfony"). It's nice for begginers! I create my first blog! But when I try to get "show" page, which displays an individual blog post identified by an id query parameter, my browser says: 'The requested URL /read was not found on this server.' I don't use .htaccess and rewrite mode of apache (version of server - Apache/2.2.22) is enable. My code ia next:

Front Controller

```
<?php
// index.php

// load and initialize any global libraries
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'controllers.php';

// route the request internally
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ('/index.php' == $uri) {
    list_action();
} elseif ('/index.php/show' == $uri && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    show_action($_GET['id']);
} else {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    echo '<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>';
}
```

Controllers.php

```
function list_action()
{
    $posts = get_all_posts();
    require 'templates/list.php';
}

function show_action($id)
{
    $post = get_post_by_id($id);
    require 'templates/show.php';
}
```

Model

```
<?php
// model.php
function open_database_connection()
{
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'zoob');
    mysql_select_db('post', $link);

    return $link;
}

function close_database_connection($link)
{
    mysql_close($link);
}

function get_all_posts()
{
    $link = open_database_connection();

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT id, title FROM post', $link);
    $posts = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    close_database_connection($link);

    return $posts;
}

function get_post_by_id($id)
{
    $link = open_database_connection();

    $id = intval($id);
    $query = 'SELECT date, title, post FROM post WHERE id = '.$id;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    close_database_connection($link);

    return $row;
}
```

Templates

```
//layout.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $content ?>
</body>
</html>

//list.php

<?php $title = 'List of Posts' ?>

<?php ob_start() ?>
<h1>List of Posts</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="/read?id=<?php echo $post['id'] ?>">
                <?php echo $post['title'] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php $content = ob_get_clean() ?>

<?php include 'layout.php' ?>

//show.php
<?php

$title = $post['title'] ?>

<?php ob_start() ?>
    <h1><?php echo $post['title'] ?></h1>

    <div class="date"><?php echo $post['date'] ?></div>
    <div class="body">
        <?php echo $post['body'] ?>
    </div>
<?php $content = ob_get_clean() ?>

<?php include 'layout.php' ?>
```

Please help me to solve and understand problem. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you defined a route /show?id={id} but your links are pointing to /read?id={id}

Comment: Oh, I changed it `/read?id={id}` to `/show?id={id}` but problem exist!

Comment: Okay, I guess you also need to make sure your links point to /index.php/show?id={id} and not just /show?id={id}

Comment: When I changed it said "Page Not Found" (`else` from front controller)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in your routes and how you refer to them.

- In list.php you refer to `/read?id=`
- In index.php you defined `/show?id=`

Change either of the two and you should be good to go.

Comment: I changed it but nothing(

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that the controller actually gets the request, you just have to debug the URI and GET requests to make sure they match your requirements.
Do something like that in your front controller :

```
<?php
// index.php

// load and initialize any global libraries
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'controllers.php';

// route the request internally
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ('/index.php' == $uri) {
    list_action();
} elseif ('/index.php/show' == $uri && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    show_action($_GET['id']);
} else {
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    echo '<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>';
    var_dump($uri);
    var_dump($_GET);
}
```

Comment: Well, when I use it tr var_dupms return next. For post with id=2 it returns: `Page Not Found

string '/index.php/show?id=2' (length=20)
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)`.

Comment: When post id=5 it returns `Page Not Found

string '/index.php/show?id=5' (length=20)
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '5' (length=1)`

Comment: Well you got your answer there :) You need to match the full URI in your elseif. You could try replacing this `elseif ('/index.php/show' == $uri && isset($_GET['id']))` with `elseif (preg_match("/\/index.php\/show\?id=[0-9]+/", $uri) && isset($_GET['id']))`

Comment: You weren't matching the correct URI since it also contains the GET query. In your code, URI had to be equal to **/index.php/show** which doesn't match **/index.php/show?id=3**, that's why I used a preg_match() instead of your == comparison, that allows you to match the whole URI pattern with a small Regex :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But it's difficult for me to understand next. Creators of Symfony are the freatest programmers in the world! It's impossible that they give such simple code with mistakes(((